# My nav menu won't work on IE < 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

My navigation menu isn't working in IE 6, 7 or 8. I'm fine with it not working in IE 6, but unfortunately it needs to work in IE 7 and 8. I am using Ubuntu, so I have been testing using http://netrenderer.com. The nav div is not floating right, and the li elements are not displayed inline. Why is this? [Here is the website](http://www.noisyleaf.co.uk).

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav a {
    height: 20px;
    width: 27%;
    margin: 0 1.7%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 25px 2%;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: thin;

    color: #555;

    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li:first-child a {
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0;
}


/* ========================
    INTERMEDIATE: IE Fixes
   ======================== */
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}




nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 38%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: What exactly is the question ? You are using HTML5 tags, which are not supported by old browsers.

Comment: I didn't know that - which of the tags are html5 tags?

Comment: `<nav>` for starters :) http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nav` tag is not supported in IE 8 and below, to circumvent this simply include an HTML5 shim that would add support for those tags which are breaking. Try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks - I added a html5shiv.js that I found on google code, and included it in my site - unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Sam - if html5shiv doesn't work, try modernizr instead. I've found it works in cases where html5shiv doesn't (which is odd because they're supposed to do the same thing for html5 tags). However you also have other issues to fix (see my answer), so you'll need to do more than just this.

Comment: @Sam im not entirely sure that the shiv you have included is working, i tried styling the nav elements to no avail even after the shiv and nothing. I updated the url of the shiv I provided which I mistakenly left out since I copied it from one of my pages but this is the one that I have always used and has always worked.

Comment: I worked out the problem - the site I was using to view the site from the perspective of IE6 must have had javascript disabled. Me and a friend revived an ancient computer (the keyboard wasn't even USB!) and managed to run internet explorer. Everything's working fine. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

**nav** tag is html5 tag  not supported in IE7/IE8 Add this in head section before : tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/master/src/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: If you want to use html5 tags, this template is better : https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

1. `<nav>` tag is not supported in IE8 or earlier.
2. `:first-child` is not supported in IE7 or earlier.
3. `:last-child` is not supported in IE8 or earlier.
4. `display: inline-block` is supported in IE6/7 but has some major bugs.

All of these issues will be breaking your menus.

To fix (1) use [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), or just don't use HTML5 tags in older IEs.

To fix (2) and (3) use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com) or [ie9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

To fix (4) use an IE-specific CSS hack to force IE6/7 to use `display:inline` instead.